# What is the type of a ng-template for strict typing in angular?

Tags: angular, angular14

i have a angular application running on version 14, and lets consider a component inside it where i have **html** as below

```
<button (click)="myfn(template)">click mE </button>
<ng-template #template>
  <some html here>
</ng-template>
```

and in **component.ts** file

```
public funtion myfn(template:any): void {
   //some action with this template like modal opening or something
}
```

Now how would i cast a type for template here in component file

I am expecting the correct type for my function parameter **template** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type is TemplateRef so:

```
public funtion myfn(template:TemplateRef<HTMLElement>): void {
   //some action with this template like modal opening or something
}
```

https://angular.io/api/core/TemplateRef